# Ajax call returns 500 if controller queries database without ->take(); other wise 200

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

I've written a google maps page for a client which includes a draw search feature written from scratch, as in draw a polygon to return locations within the polygon.

Everything works fine on the localhost.

Upon completion of the polygon (drag the final segment to the original start point) ajax calls a function that searches the database with the same DB query used in a normal non-polygon search. However, I can't get the dam thing to work without include a ->take() parameter. This makes no sense to me at all.

Controller- I've taken out some unnecessary parts of code to make it easier to read but you can see it's a regular old db query. If I replace the ->orderBy here with a ->take(some number less than or equal to total) it works fine.

```
$searchResults = DB::table('properties')
->leftJoin('propImages', 'properties.L_ListingID', '=', 'propImages.L_ListingID')
->where($propertiesArray)
->whereIn('LM_Char10_1', $waterArray)
->whereIn('L_Class', $propTypes)
->when($residential==1, function($query) use ($bed, $bath) {// when residental is true, get beds/bath criteria return
    $query->where([['L_Keyword3', '>=', $bed],['LM_Int1_1', '>=', $bath]]);  
}); 
$sr = $searchResults->orderBy('L_AskingPrice', 'asc')->get();
```

view

```
google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, 'polygoncomplete', function (polygon) {

                        console.log('polygon complete');
                        $('#overMapLoadIcon').css('display', 'inline');
                        //Hide drawl button
                        $('#deletePoly').css('display', 'inline');
                        $('#updatePolySearch').css('display', 'inline');
                        drawingManager.setOptions({
                          drawingControl: false
                        });
                        //Set draw mode to hand
                        drawingManager.set('drawingMode');

                        polyPoints = [];// create an arry of all the point's GPS coords in the polygon by looping through them
                          for (var i = 0; i < polygon.getPath().getLength(); i++) {//For Each Polygon point
                              var poylygonCoord = polygon.getPath().getAt(i).toUrlValue(6);

                              var coords = poylygonCoord.split(",");
                              var lat = coords[0];
                              var lng = coords[1];
                              polyPoints.push([lat,lng]);
                              //console.log(lat+'    '+lng);
                          }

                          // with array of pollygon points coordinates, send to controller with search criteria
                          var waterType = $('#typeOfWaterfront').val();
                          var priceSlider = $('#priceSlider').val();
                          var footageSlider = $('#footageSlider').val();
                          var beds = $("body").find("[aria-selected=true]").parent().attr("data-original-index");
                          var baths = $("body").find("[aria-selected=true]").parents().attr("data-original-index");
                          var residential = $('[name*="residential"]:checkbox:checked').length > 0;
                          var vacantland = $('[name*="vacantland"]:checkbox:checked').length > 0;
                          var commercial = $('[name*="commercial"]:checkbox:checked').length > 0;
                          var condos = $('[name*="condos"]:checkbox:checked').length > 0;
                          //$("body").find("[aria-selected=true]").parents().attr("data-original-index");

                          var polyPointsString = JSON.stringify(polyPoints);
                          var CSRF_TOKEN = $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content');
                          $.ajax({
                              url: '<?php echo URL::to("/searchByPoly/") ?>',
                              type: 'POST',

                              data: {_token: CSRF_TOKEN, polyPoints: polyPointsString,
                               waterFrontType: waterType,
                               price: priceSlider,
                               footage: footageSlider,
                               bed: beds,
                               bath: baths,
                               res: residential,
                               vacant: vacantland,
                               comm: commercial,
                               condo: condos },
                              success: function (data) {
                                jsonProps = JSON.parse(data);
                                $('#overMapLoadIcon').css('display', 'none');
                                removeAllMarkers();
                                markers=[];

                                for (var i = 0; i < jsonProps.length; i++) {
                                  //L_DisplayId
                                  placeMarkerFromPoly(jsonProps[i]);  
                                }

                              }
                          });
```

This can't be a token issue since I can still get the ajax to work. I'm stupped. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

*----**UPDATE**---*

The network response is 500. I get nothing back in the form of a preview. There is no laravel error message

My Log file.

Should I be attaching the bottom few lines like so?:

```
#73 /var/www/upnorthproperties.net/public_html/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(699): Illuminate\Routing\Router->runRouteWithinStack(Object(Illuminate\Routing\Route), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#74 /var/www/upnorthproperties.net/public_html/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(675): Illuminate\Routing\Router->dispatchToRoute(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#75 /var/www/upnorthproperties.net/public_html/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(246): Illuminate\Routing\Router->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#76 [internal function]: Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#77 /var/www/upnorthproperties.net/public_html/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(52): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#78 /var/www/upnorthproperties.net/public_html/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/CheckForMaintenanceMode.php(44): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#79 [internal function]: Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#80 /var/www/upnorthproperties.net/public_html/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(136): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#81 [internal function]: Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#82 /var/www/upnorthproperties.net/public_html/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(32): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#83 [internal function]: Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#84 /var/www/upnorthproperties.net/public_html/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(103): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#85 /var/www/upnorthproperties.net/public_html/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(132): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))
#86 /var/www/upnorthproperties.net/public_html/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(99): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#87 /var/www/upnorthproperties.net/public_html/laravel/public/index.php(54): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#88 {main}
```

Comment: What's being logged to your `storage/logs/laravel.log` file? If you have your network tab opened in your browser, you can watch for an Ajax request, and if/when it fails, you can click on it to preview status codes, error messages, etc etc. What does it say there? Do some debugging and update your question with those answers.

Comment: I would say that most likely your query is getting too many results, and you are running out of memory when you don't supply a limit (via `take()` method).

Comment: Updated, if you're right patricus how should I go about troubleshooting it to prove this is the cause? I've rewritten the query to get everything with the left join to make the results as big as possible and it returns fine with ajax, so it doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 0):

patricus, you were correct. I've been testing it and it appears my digital ocean dropplet couldn't handle that many returns. I was essentially returning most of around 12 thousand properties and then going through each one to see if it's within the polygon.

I was going to fix it by switching to a javascript front end solution for the polygon check but I found that a large number of the properties were from another county that we will never need so I simply reduced the size of the database, now it works.

I wouldn't have come up with that solution without your comment. Thanks  patricus